# Java Application becomes slow and takes more time to update UI

Tags: java, multithreading, serial-communication

Hi I have an application which communicates with my device through USB serial communication. The program is simple read the data sent by the device and plot it in UI. But as I run the program some 20+ times the UI starts to update slower and slower.

```
synchronized (lockObject) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (sessionStatus) { 
                    if (isSerialPortOpen() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        createPacketAndWrite(getCurrentState());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100); 
                            serialCommunication.readData();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            log.error("IO error while reading data from serialCommunication object" + e);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            log.error("InterruptedException in startCommunication()" + e);
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        threadPool.execute(r);
```

After 50 times the application becomes not responding and I have to close the application. But the communication between the device and the PC is still continuing.

I have 2 screens in this application, in one screen i read the data from the device for a particular time interval and then move to next screen.

There are 3 buttons in the first screen, button1 will initiate communication with the device, button2 will run the device in a different mode, button3 will stop the communication and move to next screen.

button3 will load some values from the device to be displayed in the second screen.

On button1, i am also loading the next elements like table, graph etc but empty.
on button2, i am loading the data into the table and the graph values.

My application takes time to load the UI,
1) When button1 is clicked.
2) When button3 is clicked.
3) When the next is loaded, the app takes time to load the data in the graphs.

Can someone help me?

Comment: With just that small extract from your code there is no real way to help you here. Try to use a debugger to see where your programm uses most of its computation time to narrow down the scope of your search.

Comment: There's not enough here to understand your problem.  From the sparse context it seems you're starting 20 processes that are all trying to access the serial port -- that's going cause some performance issues all by itself, but honestly i can't tell if that interpretation is relavent.

Comment: When I read some articles, during Thread.sleep(), the Main thread sends interrupt(), Which will be caught by the catch block, then how is it running so many threads, is there a way to stop them?

Comment: Unrelated: `while (sessionStatus)` ... so you have a boolean variable called sessionStatus, which you use to control a loop?! Terrible naming here. A status is true or false? Depending how you declared that field/variable ... there might also be a lot of potential multi threading issues hiding there. Like: is it volatile?

Comment: sessionStatus becomes true when I connect with my device and stays true until i disconnect from the device